# How to include 2 fragments inside one activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments: `ls_fragment` and `pm_fragment`.
I'm trying to show the `pm_fragment` in the portrait mode and both fragments in the landscape mode, but my code doesn't work. In the portrait mode it works, but in the landscape mode it shows only one fragment.

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    LM_Fragment lm_fragment = new LM_Fragment();
    PM_Fragment pm_fragment = new PM_Fragment();

    /**
     * Check the device orientation and act accordingly
     */
    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        /**
         * Landscape mode of the device
         */
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, lm_fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, pm_fragment);
    }else{
        /**
         * Portrait mode of the device
         */
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, pm_fragment);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

and LM_Fragment class (the same goes for PM_Fragment class):

```
public class LM_Fragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**
     * Inflate the layout for this fragment
     */
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.lm_fragment, container, false);
} 
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<framelayout
    android:name="com.example.myfragments.LM_Fragment"
    android:id="@+id/lm_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<framelayout
    android:name="com.example.myfragments.PM_Fragment"
    android:id="@+id/pm_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

lm_fragment.xml (the same goes for pm_fragment.xml);

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#7bae16">

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/landscape_message"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="20px" />

<!-- More GUI components go here  -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

I have just updated your code a little and it works.

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
/**
 * Created by Ravi on 09/07/16.
 */
public class Test12 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test123);

        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        MyFrag1 ls_fragment = new Myfrag1();
        Myfrag2 pm_fragment = new Myfrag2();

        /**
         * Check the device orientation and act accordingly
         */
        if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            /**
             * Landscape mode of the device
             */
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView1, ls_fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView2, pm_fragment);
        }else{
            /**
             * Portrait mode of the device
             */
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView1, pm_fragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView1"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView2"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to **remove** below line from your `MainActivity` code.

```
fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, pm_fragment)
```

I guess you misplaced this code in your activity class because when you checked that the orientation of the device is Landscape, you are replacing `android.R.id.content` with `lm_fragment`.

Comment: i need to have both fragment in landscape mode....can you understand me? this line you say doesn't exist in my code(fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, pm_fragment)) . I just use replace method.